# Unable to diagnose missing semicolon

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm unable to diagnose the error message which shows up as "Missing semicolon" in the following usage of `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\zta}{10/pi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xb}{-pi/3}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xe}{pi/3}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-pi, xmax=pi,ymin=0,ymax=1.05,
                    xlabel={$\chi$},ylabel={$f_r$},
                    declare function={f(\x)=tanh(\zta*(\x-\xb))-tanh(\zta(\x-\xe));},
                    samples=100]
            \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,f(x)/2);         
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A plot of  $f_r(\chi;\frac{30}{\pi},-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3})$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can't point where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In your `\addplot` line, you have to surround both `x` and `f(x)/2` with braces such that you have `\addplot[blue, ultra thick] ({x},{f(x)/2});`

Answer (score 1):

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zta}{10/pi}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xb}{-pi/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xe}{pi/3}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-pi,xmax=pi,ymin=0,ymax=1.05,xlabel={$\chi$},ylabel={$f_r$},declare function={f(\x)=tanh(\zta*(\x-\xb))-tanh(\zta(\x-\xe));},samples=100]
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (\x,{f(\x)/2});         
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A plot of  $f_r(\chi;\frac{30}{\pi},-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3})$ over$[-\pi,\pi]$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

According to your code, here's what I've got:
[image]

That was not an answer only because I can't write all of this in a comment! and of course to show you the result that I have a doubt about it!